# What's the extract reason of std::hex output in char but hexstring?

Tags: c++, hex

Code firstly,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0x41;
        
    // output A but 41
    std::cout << std::hex << x << std::endl;
}
```

Why `x` is treated as a `char` by `std::cout` ?

Why `std::cout` cannot output hexstring here?

Thanks!

Comment: Its type is `unsigned char`, so it's a character. Cast it to `int`.

Comment: It's not reasonable. I do want to see the hex value of a `char` or `unsigned char`. Am I wrong? I don't think this thing happens in any other language, even in C. So, is there no way to output hexstring of `unsigned char` without casting in C++?

Comment: I would argue that the entire `<iostream>` infrastructure is not reasonable. `std::format` prints `unsigned char`s as numbers: `std::format("{:x}", (unsigned char)0x41)` -> `41`, and `std::format("{}", (unsigned char)0x41)` -> `65`.

Comment: In C with printf etc. , the type of the argument is undefined and interpreted at runtime by the format specifier.  It is the behaviour of the C++ type system and the availability of operator overload functions that are resolved at compile time by operand type.  You are asking it to print a character so it prints a character.  If you want it to treat the character as an integer, you have to coerce that.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to do it in C either without conversion to a different type. Try `unsigned char c = 0x41; printf("%c", c);`, for instance.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : Indeed the idea of "insertion operators" probably started as in experiment in what could be done with operator overloading, but the need for cumbersome and confusing io manipulators, and type casting to use the intended overload make it rather more difficult to use than intended.  Thankfully a better idea came along - eventually.  However it swaps static resolution if type for runtime interpretation, so is not precisely equivalent.

Comment: Smallest possible fix (one character): https://godbolt.org/z/vroceso5G

Comment: @MarekR : but it is not a competition ;-)  Sometimes clarity is better than brevity.  There's a difference between terse and succinct.

Answer (score 3):

The operator overload `std::ostream::operator<<(ostream& os, unsigned char c)` is defined to output a *character*.  If that was not so and it treated the operand as an integer, you'd have the opposite problem - no means of outputting a single character.  The io manipulator affects only integer value output.

The solution is trivial - simply cast the character to an `unsigned` to force the `std::ostream::operator<<(ostream& os, unsigned int c)` overload to be invoked instead:

```cpp
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(x) << std::endl;
```

or

```cpp
std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned)x << std::endl;
```

or by temporary construction:

```cpp
std::cout << std::hex << unsigned(x) << std::endl;
```

Comment: `+x` is nicer and cleaner: https://godbolt.org/z/vroceso5G

Comment: @MarekR :  Post an answer - it is valid, and a worthy suggestion, but I would not recommend it personally (or accept it in a code review from my colleagues).  It relies on arcane knowledge of implicit type promotion in arithmetic expressions, rather than being an explicit conversion.  I don't hold with the "less typing" argument over clarity of intent.  Besides the existing behaviour has already confused the OP `+x` will truly look like voodoo magic ;-)